# Finding minimum of $\frac{3a+x}{\sqrt[4]{a^3x}}$

Tags: calculus, optimization

If $a>0$ and be a constant and $x$ be variable, what is the minimum of $\dfrac{3a+x}{\large\sqrt[4]{a^3x}}$ ?

$1)4\qquad2)3a\qquad3)3\qquad4)2a$

I tried finding derivative of $y=\dfrac{3a+x}{\large\sqrt[4]{a^3x}}$ and equate it to zero ( first I took logarithm to make calculations easier) :

$$\ln(y)=\ln(3a+x)-\frac14\ln(a^3x)$$
$$\frac{y'}y=\frac{1}{3a+x}-\frac{1}{4x}$$
$$y'=\dfrac{3a+x}{\large\sqrt[4]{a^3x}}\times\left(\frac{1}{3a+x}-\frac{1}{4x}\right)$$
By $\frac{1}{3a+x}-\frac{1}{4x}=0$ we have $x=a$, plugging in the original equation we have $y=4$  so it seems the correct answer is $4$. but my question is: Why not having $y=\dfrac{3a+x}{\large\sqrt[4]{a^3x}}=0$? (because we have $y'=0$) so thee answer be $y=0$ .

Comment: Hint: If $x=-3a$, then the denominator of $\dfrac{3a+x}{\large\sqrt[4]{a^3x}}$ is not defined.

Comment: Oh I got it thank you !

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Comment: @callculus: $x > 0$, so $x = -3a < 0$ is not in the domain.

Comment: I think we have $a>0$ not $x$

Comment: @amirali: But then $x > 0$ as well.

Comment: @ODETutor I got your point. thanks!

Comment: @amirali: My pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** AM-GM inequality : $a+a+a+x \ge 4\sqrt[4]{....}$ . Can you wrap it up ?

Comment: Ok so we have $y\ge1$.

Comment: @amirali: $y \ge 4$.

Comment: Oh yes. you are right! very good approach!